# CakePHP question: What's the difference between these two routing?

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-1.3

This is one =>

```
echo $this->Html->link('Edit',
                            array('controller'=>'comments','action'=>'edit',$comment['Comment']['id']));
```

This is another one in form =>

```
echo $this->Form->create('Comment', 
                array('url'=>array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' =>'add', $listposts['Post']['id']) )
                );
    echo $this->Form->input('post_id',array('type'=>'hidden','style'=>'width:30%','value'=>$listposts['Post']['id']));  
    echo $this->Form->input('name',array('style'=>'width:30%'));
    echo $this->Form->input('email',array('style'=>'width:30%'));   
    echo $this->Form->input('body',array('rows'=>'5'));

    echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

Is it possible to do echo $this->Form->create like the previous one ? Why do i need 'url'=>array(..) why not like this =>

```
echo $this->Form->create('Comment',array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' =>'add', $listposts['Post']['id']));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that is tthat the url-array is an argument in the link()-function of the HTML-helper. If you take a look at the declaration:

```
link(string $title, mixed $url = null, array $options = array(),  
     string $confirmMessage = false)
```

So you pass the url as second argument without the `$url` name as you would do with other methods.

Howerver, the declaration of the create()-method in the Form-helper is:

```
create(string $model = null, array $options = array())
```

Notice that there is just one $options-array. So your url here is a member of an array rather then a member of an argument list. In associative arrays you can't simply leave the keys so using the url-array without explicitly naming the key should not work.

For more information see the Docs for this methods:
[HTML->link()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1442/link)
[Form->create()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1384/Creating-Forms)

Comment: How can i pass the post id as second parameter with $this->Html->link('Edit comment',array(..));

Comment: By appending it to the url-array: `echo $this->Html->link('Edit', array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'edit', $comment['Comment']['id'], $post_id));`. Of course, that will also change the resulting url: `/comments/edit/comment_id/post/id`.